# Prove $dom f = N$ for $f = \{(x,y) \in N X N : (x = 2y) \lor (x = 2y + 1)\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Here's a little background to my question.

I'm given the following relation:
$$f = {(x,y) \in N x N : (x = 2y) \lor (x = 2y + 1)}$$

I have already proved it is a function;

> Suppose $(x,y) \in f$ and $(x,z) \in f$. Then $2y = x$ or $2y = x -
> > 1$, and $2z = x$ or $2z = x - 1$.
>  Thus y = z.
>  This means that
>   $[(x,y) \in f \land (x,z) \in f] \Rightarrow (y=z)$
>  Thus $f$ is a
>   function.

Please verify this is correct. Now I want to further this, as I am proving that $f$ is a function from N to N. So I need to show that $dom f = N$.

> Suppose $x \in dom f$.

What does this mean exactly? That $f(n) = m$ for some $m \in Z$? Or does it mean that $f(n) = 2m$ or $2m + 1$ for some $m \in Z?$

After that, I need to show the other side, that $N$ is a subset of $dom f$. I am assuming this has something to do with being even or odd.

Any tips for this? I've been stuck for a few hours trying to understand the problem where we have a multiple of $y$ in the function.

Comment: Didn't you post this earlier today?

Comment: Yes I did. I'm not entirely sure how Stack Exchange deals with old topics. I was wondering if they become dead air without the bounty (which wasn't an option for another two days I believe?).

Comment: @dewick49: When you say N, do you mean $\mathbb{N}$ or just some set N ?

Comment: After Suppose $x \in dom f$, You refer to Z - should it not be $\mathbb{N}$ again ? You defined your function as a set of ordered pairs in $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$